# apt-get update fails to configure linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dpkg

When I recently tried to use apt-get upgrade to install the most recent updates, the process failed while configuring `linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic`. I can not remove / purge the package, and can not upgrade or install any other packages. '`tail /var/log/dpkg.log`' returns this:

```
2013-05-24 10:04:44 startup packages purge
2013-05-24 10:04:44 status half-installed linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic 3.2.0-43.68
2013-05-24 10:04:54 remove linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic 3.2.0-43.68 <none>
2013-05-24 10:04:54 status half-installed linux-image-3.2.0-43-generic 3.2.0-43.68
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, due to the fact that the device was full or almost full. Check with `df -k`.